# Eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the $N\times N$ matrix defined as $A_{ij}=1+\lambda, \forall i\leq j$ and $A_{ij}=\lambda,\forall i>j$. $\lambda$ is some given positive constant. Can we comment on the Eigen vector corresponding to largest eigenvalue of this matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the case $n=3$ ([Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2Bt%2C1%2Bt%2C1%2Bt%7D%2C%7Bt%2C1%2Bt%2C1%2Bt%7D%2C%7Bt%2Ct%2C1%2Bt%7D%7D)), I don't think one can say much, apart from what Perron-Frobenius theorem implies. However, the structure of this matrix is quite special (even among Toeplitz matrices), so there is perhaps some nice way to solve the eigenproblem numerically.

Using Perron-Frobenius theorem, if $x$ is *the* probability vector corresponding to the dominant eigenvalue $k$, then by considering $\mathbf 1^TAx$, it is easy to see that $k\in n\lambda+[1,n]$. The lower end of this interval provides a somewhat sharper bound than the leftmost end of the Gerschgorin discs. It is also easy to see that the entries of the (positive) eigenvector $x$ must be arranged in descending order.

Comment: I was actually looking for that property about the entries of x being in descending order. How do you see that??

Comment: @dineshdileep $x=\frac1kAx$, so $x_i=\frac1kA_{i\ast}x$. Since every row of $A$ is entrywise greater than or equal to the next row, and $k,A,x$ are all positive, it follows that $x_i\ge x_{i+1}$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This is helpful indeed..

Comment: In a different direction. Does row sum being high guarantee this ordering?. For instance, consider the positive matrix such that $A_{ii}=1$ and $A_{ij}+A_{ji}=1$. I randomly generated such matrices and observed that as the dimension increases, normalized (sum to 1) row sum becomes the normalized (sum to 1) perron vector. Are you familiar with such patterns and related literature.

Comment: @dineshdileep Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: sorry, one more question. Is this ordering preserved if it is sum of a jordan matrix(ones in main diagonal and super diagonal above it) and a nilpotent matrix (which is strictly upper triangular and also has zeros on super diagonal above main diagonal).

Comment: @dineshdileep Hmm, what a strange question!  ;-D  In this case the only eigenspace of this matrix is spanned by $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)^T$, so, of course, the entries of any nonnegative eigenvector must appear in descending order.

Comment: you wont believe, this comes from an application :)

Comment: Does this happen irrespective of the nilpotent portion. So, to make it more clear for you. My matrix is $A=J+N+\lambda ee^T$ where $J$ is the jordan matrix, $N$ is the nilpotent matrix who is strictly upper triangular with zeros on super diagonal as well. $e$ is the all ones vector and $\lambda$ is a small positive constant. Effectively, the last portion, makes it irreducible as you have probably already figured :)

Comment: Sorry, if you look at the original question, that is actually a upper triangular matrix + $\lambda ee^T$. This is to make the matrix completely positive to make sure of the existence of perron vector.

Comment: That's interesting. Numerical evidences are in favour of a descending order. Let me think about it.

Comment: @dineshdileep OK, here's an idea. I think it works although I haven't worked out all the details. Let $B=J+N$. First, try to prove that when $k$ is sufficiently large, $B^k$ eventually will have the property that $(B^k)_{ij}>(B^k)_{i+1,,j}$ when the $(i,j)$-entry is off-diagonal and in the upper triangular part. So, similarly, for such an $(i,j)$, we will also have $(B^k)_{ij}>(B^k)_{i,,j-1}$ when $k$ is large. (to be cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) It follows from the binomial expansion of $(B+\lambda ee^T)^k$ that, when $k$ is large and $\lambda>0$ is small, every row of $A^k$ will strictly dominate the next row. Since eigenvectors of $A$ are also eigenvectors of $A^k$, we can now play the same trick in my answer.

Comment: sounds intuitive :). Let me work on it.

Comment: I was able to generate some numerical examples wherein this is wrong. I hope I didn't waste your time.:(:(